# Space of image than left and right of the page

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout

I have an ImageView in top of RelativeLayout but image in RelativeLayout has space than right and left of page(this space is a little). I don't know how can solve this :( if i set image with more width, again image has space than right and left of the page. Why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/registerAction"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/testing" 
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I test my program on the Emulator. Do this problem has for Emulator? If i test program on the phone, the problem will be solve?
Thanks.Cheers

Comment: add android:layout_alignParentLeft="true";

Comment: not able to under stand properly , can please attach a screen shot and a little bit clarification of what yu want exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try it with Device, it will solve your problem.

And please add one attribute for your ImageView, android:scaleType="fitXY".

Comment: Thanks.When i add android:scaleType="fitXy" to xml file, the problem solved even i try in Emulator. Why, when add this line to xml file, the problem solved? Why ImageView hase this problem ?

Comment: partik, please say to me another my question in above comments :)

Comment: android:scaleType="fitXY"'s work is, it make Image fir to x-axis and y-axis. There may be problem with your image, it may be small or there may be transparent border  etc etc. But when you do this fitxy, it will make your Image fit to the screens x-axis and y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your image. It might have transparant or white space along the border.
Aligning images depends upong your image content too